Как правильно продублировать код javascript
Хочу разместить на страницах два независимых sidebar которые имеют такой код:
var toggleBtn = document.querySelector('.sidebar-toggle');
var sidebar = document.querySelector('.sidebar');

toggleBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  toggleBtn.classList.toggle('is-closed');
  sidebar.classList.toggle('is-closed');
})

Я сделала правки css и html чтобы они не повторялись. Для другого sidebar отредактировала javascript так:
var toggleBtn = document.querySelector('.support-author-toggle');
var sidebar = document.querySelector('.support-author');

toggleBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  toggleBtn.classList.toggle('in-closed');
  sidebar.classList.toggle('in-closed');
})

По отдельности они работают а находясь оба на одной странице один из них перестает работать. Все скрипты у меня находятся в одном файле main-castom.js
Исходный код codepen


var toggleBtn = document.querySelector('.sidebar-toggle');
var sidebar = document.querySelector('.sidebar');

toggleBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  toggleBtn.classList.toggle('is-closed');
  sidebar.classList.toggle('is-closed');
})
// COLORS
$white: #fff;
$main-color: #29C7D2;
$sub-color: #253FE1;

$color__bg: $sub-color;
$color__sidebar: $white;
$color__toggle: $sub-color;

// SIZES
$width__sidebar: 15em;

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: $color__bg;
}

.sidebar-toggle {
float: right;
  
  &.is-closed {
    transform: translateX(.3em) rotate(0deg);  
  }
  
  .icon {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    color: $white;
  }
}

.sidebar {
  width: $width__sidebar;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #1d1e22;
  transition: .7s;
  
  &.is-closed {
    transform: translateX(-30em);
  }
}
.sidebar-d {
float: right;
}
<div class="sidebar is-closed">
  <button class="sidebar-toggle">кнопка внутри sidebar</button>
</div>
<div class="sidebar-d">
<button class="sidebar-toggle">кнопка на странице</button>
</div>




переменные тоже надо переименовать

и обернуть в фукнцию с входящим параметром селектора. Тогда и дубликата кода не будет

Замените устаревшие var на const и сразу увидите проблему

@SwaD, спорно про устаревшесть

Дублирование кода - плохая затея.
Лучше делать переиспользуемый код. Вот пример, как это можно сделать в вашем случае:
function startSideBar(selector) {
  const toggleBtn = document.querySelector(`.${selector}-toggle`);
  const sidebar = document.querySelector(`.${selector}`);

  toggleBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    toggleBtn.classList.toggle('is-closed');
    sidebar.classList.toggle('is-closed');
  });
  // Опционально, если нужен доступ к элементам за пределами функции
  return [toggleBtn, sidebar];
}

// Вызываем функцию для каждого селектора
startSideBar('sidebar');
startSideBar('support-author');
// Если нужно получить доступ к элементу за пределами функции, то вызов будет выглядеть так
const [toggleBtn, sidebar] = startSideBar('sidebar');
const [supportBtn, supportSidebar] = startSideBar('support-author');

Создается фукнция, которая выбирает нужные элементы по селектору, переданному в функцию.
Создает обработчик клика на кнопку
(Опционально - можно убрать, если не используется) Возвращает найденные элементы(кнопку и сайдбар)

Спасибо вам большое за помощь. Подскажите еще такой вопрос, когда я помещаю одну кнопку вызова sidebar в шаблон страницы а другую в сам sidebar он перестает отзываться на кнопку и не появляется. тест

@Lisaa Это лучше смотреть на конкретном примере конечно. Что за "шаблон" страницы и что значит в сам sidebar? Один из возможных вариантов, что скрипт срабатывает быстрее, чем HTML разметка полностью прогрузится браузером. Тогда можно вызывать функцию по событию полного закгрузки DOM браузером. Но опять же, нужен пример. Что бы проверить, что происходит, можо добавить console.log() в фукнцию и посмотреть, выбирает ли кнопку скрипт(если нет ошибок, выбирает) и console.log() пихнуть в само событие клика, что бы понимать, срабатывает ли оно.

Добавила пример, кнопка снаружи не отвечает а та что внутри работает. Та же ситуация и с вашим примером.

@Lisaa querySelector Выбирает первый попавшийся элемент с заданным селектором(вы ищете по имени класса). Поэтому первая кнопка выбирается всегда, а вторая никогда. Можно кнопкам добавить уникальные ID и обращаться к элементам по ID getElementById
